# Multiple layers of JPanels. Want to repaint middle panel without it covering up the more up front panels

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am making a game. It consists of a JPanel that contains several other JPanels. 1 bottom panel, with buttons, 1 top panel, with buttons, one panel in between those two panels that is the regular Game screen, and then several SlidingPanes and dynamic JPanels that slide in or pop up from clicking buttons on the top or bottom panel or from clicking somewhere on the game screen.

Right now, I am drawing a truck that follows a path on the game screen. The truck draws fine, but whenever I click a button to open the sliding pane, it gets drawn over by the Game Screen panel, making it flicker as it opens and then not show until I mouse over it. The Game Screens paintComponent method is the cause of this, it is bringing the Game Screen to the front whenever it's repaint method is called, when I want it to stay behind the Sliding Panes or panels that pop up on top of it.

Is there a way to make the game screen stay at the layer it is without paintComponent bringing it to the top?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect anyone to know what you're doing wrong without some code. Your best bet is to try create a minimal compilable runnable example that demonstrates the problem and which has no code unrelated to the problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: See: [How to Use Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)